# How to count the elements in an Array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, parsing

```
result=  [
  {
    "range_id": 18,
    "id": 1,
    "start": 1863,
    "end": 1875,
  },
  {
    "range_id": 12,
    "id": 2,
    "start": 1820,
    "end": 1844,
  },
  {
    "range_id": 19,
    "id": 3,
    "start": 1875,
    "end": 1887,
  },
  {
    "range_id": 12,
    "id": 4,
    "start": 1844,
    "end": 1856,
  },
  {
    "range_id": 18,
    "id": 5,
    "start": 1887,
    "end": 1899,
  },
  {
    "range_id": 12,
    "id": 6,
    "start": 1856,
    "end": 1868,
  }
]
```

What i like to do is check for "range_id" values in result and count same range_id and if range_id.count <= 3 i perform certain tasks otherwise skip, but not sure how to implement.
Can we do in ruby something like:

```
next unless result.range_id.count <=3
{
do something
}
```

Comment: A specific `range_id` like `18`, for example? Or should each `range_id` in `result` occur at least 3 times? Or at least one `range_id`, no matter which?

Comment: When you give an example you should always show the desired result. The result should be a valid and complete Ruby object (no "etc." or "..."). If you feel the complete desired result is too long to show in your answer it generally means that your example is unnecessarily large. Sometimes askers don't show the desired result because they think it should be obvious from their words, but they may be wrong. In any event, make examples no larger than necessary to make your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can this one-liner to count the number of occurrences of each `range_id`:

```
result.map { |hash| hash[:range_id] }.tally
#=> { 18 => 2, 12 => 3, 19 => 1 }
```

You can then iterate that hash and handle each `range_id` depending on it count:

```
range_id_counters = result.map { |hash| hash[:range_id] }.tally
range_id_counters.each do |range_id, count|
  puts("#{range_id} occurs only #{count} times") if count <= 3
end
# 18 occurs only 2 times
# 12 occurs only 3 times                                                                                                                         
# 19 occurs only 1 times
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are couple more options

1. You could use nested selects to get the records that have 3 or less

```
selection_of_items = result.select do |a|
    result.select { |b| b[:'range_id'] == a[:'range_id']}.size <= 3
end

selection_of_items.each do |c|
  # do something
end
```

2. You can avoid the O(n^2) above, instead of using an array to store the items you might try a hash instead that uses the range_id as the key, and a 'Set' to store items with the identical range_id
   ex. {"18"=>{{"range_id"=>18, "id"=>1, "start"=>1863, "end"=>1875}, ...}, ...}

```
# using your result array from above
hash_result = {}
result.each do |obj|
  hash_result.store(
    obj[:'range_id'], hash_result.fetch(obj[:'range_id'], Set.new).add(obj)
  )
end
# then use the new structure
# {
#   18=>{{:range_id=>18, :id=>1, :start=>1863, :end=>1875}, {:range_id=>18, :id=>5, :start=>1887, :end=>1899}},
#   12=>{{:range_id=>12, :id=>2, :start=>1820, :end=>1844},{:range_id=>12, :id=>4, :start=>1844, :end=>1856},
#     {:range_id=>12, :id=>6, :start=>1856, :end=>1868}},
#   19=>{{:range_id=>19, :id=>3, :start=>1875, :end=>1887}}
# }
hash_result.each do |k,v|
  next if v.count > 3
  v.each do |d|
     #do something
  end 
end
```